# How can I ask what kind of evening one is having?

Tags: english-to-japanese

I want to say "what kind of evening are you having?".  I think 何で can be used, but I dont know how to fit evening into the sentence structure.  I have:

何でイブニングがあるか？

Is this right?  Would the sentence structure be similar in general?

"What kind of X do you have?"

Comment: Can you give the context you have in mind? This going to dictate what expression you use.  It sounds like you want to walk up people at a party your giving and　ask 'how is going? are you having a good time?'

Comment: @Tim - Yes thats pretty close.  Its actually slang I use with a friend.  So I was looking for a close literal translation.  But a party context will work

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Oh then it would be more like 楽しんでる？ maybe?

Comment: &ちょこれーと - Your answer works.  "どんな" was the part tripping me up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

何でイブニングがあるか？sounds to me like "Why are there evenings?". 
"What kind of~" would be "どんな~", and "What kind of X do you have?" literally translates to どんなXを持っていますか. e.g.

> どんなドレスを持っていますか? What kind of dress do you have?

When you ask how one's spending their time I think you could say

> どんな～を過ごしていますか。
>   どんな～をお過ごしですか。(formal)
>   ～を、いかがお過ごしですか。(formal)

...normally in writing.

Answer (score 1):

If it is already the evening ("How is your evening? Having fun?"), you can say:

> 今日楽しんでる？

(inspired by ちょこれーと's comment)

If it is not the evening already ("What are your plans for this evening?"):

> 今晩何してる？

Comment: Never heard a Japanese speaker say 今晩楽しんでる？.  Can't imagine one saying it, either.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya: Thanks for your feedback. I was thinking about 今日楽しんでる (which is not rare) but I should not have adapted to 今晩.

Comment: @Tokyo Nagoya, I trust your expertise, but could you explain why using 今晩 there would be so unnatural? (I know we are making literal translations from english which obviously is unnatural but if you would elucidate your criticism for my benefit, I would be greatly appreciative.)

Comment: @yadokari: A Google search for my initial sentence leads to only 7 results... Google is my expertise checker :-)

Comment: I have learned from Sawa Sensei that  Google as an expertise checker is untrustworthy.